# How to create and link to pages dynamically based off of objects?

Tags: javascript, html

I just figured out how to read in objects from my Mongo database and display them in table.

```
for (i = 0; i<teamlist.count;) {
    strTeam = strTeam + "<tr><td><a href=''>" + teamlist.teams[i].teamName + "</td></tr>";
    i = i+1;
}
strTeam = "<table border='1'>" + strTeam + "</table>"
```

I now have a table filled with clickable links of all my team names, though the links take you nowhere.

Whats the best practice to go about defining the links to direct you to a page that simply displays the name of the team that was clicked?

Comment: Do the teams have their own pages that you can link already? Or is your question really about routing (and not javascript and HTML)?

Comment: I have not created their own pages. I was under the impression it could be done dynamically?

Comment: You can do it dynamically but you need a url tht would either display the team details or send JSON data so your script can fetch it. If you already have team details in your teamlist object you don't need to re connect to the server for it.

Answer (score 0):

first: the href-attribute of the 'a' - element is empty, so of course the link takes you nowhere.

what technique do you use server-side? sure you can 'dynamically' create pages, but you first have to implement the prototype of such page and then let it get the data from the link when called. the team's data must be stored somewhere (e.g. database) and retrieved by the page for display.

if you use php, you can pass the individual data of each team via $_GET like so:

```
<a href="page.php?team=foo">see foo</a>
```

then, serverside, you extract data from $_GET:

```
$foo = $_GET['team']; // is 'foo'  
//then do something with foo, maybe a db-query, and show data as HTML
```

be carefull with user-provided data on your serverside application!
you should somehow validate those $_GET variables before using them; just google for SQL-Injection.

Answer (score 0):

As the following code will show it's kind of a pain to generate html with JavaScript. If it gets a lot more complected maybe you should google for mustache template.

I assume you're trying this on a modern browser and your the teamlist contains certain information, please let me know if you need any more help.

One tip when you try code is to use console.log. When using this in Chrome or Firefox with firebug plugin you can press F12 to open the developer tools. It should open in the console tab. When you log objects you can click on it in the console and inspect the object's details.

```
teamlist = {};
teamlist.teams=[
  {teamName:"team one",teamDetail:"team one details"},
  {teamName:"team two",teamDetail:"team two details"}
];
console.log("teamlist is now:",teamlist);
var myapp =  myapp || {};//innit myapp namespace
myapp.createTable=function(){
  var df = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  table = document.createElement("table"),
  i = 0,row,cel;
  while(i<teamlist.teams.length){
    cel = this.cel(teamlist.teams[i]);
    row = this.row();
    row.appendChild(cel);
    table.appendChild(row);
    i++;
  }
  table.onclick=this.toggleDetails;
  document.body.appendChild(table);
};
myapp.row = function(){
  return document.createElement("tr");
};
myapp.cel = function(paramObj){
  var cel = document.createElement("td"),//<=notice the comma, adding
     //more variables without having to specify "var"
  detail = document.createElement("div");
  detail.appendChild(document.createTextNode(paramObj.teamDetail));
  detail.style.display="none";
  detail.style.position="relative";
  detail.style.top="10px";
  detail.style.left="-50px";
  detail.style.backgroundColor="#AAAAAA";
  cel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(paramObj.teamName));
  cel.appendChild(detail);
  return cel;
};
myapp.toggleDetails = function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName!=="TD")
    return;
  var details = e.target.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  var visible = details.style.display;
  visible = (visible==="inline")?"none":"inline";
  details.style.display=visible;
};
myapp.createTable();
```